# Find range / datasource of Listboxitem (single selection)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an UserForm for searching through data, which is located in Sheet(2). The search-results are listed in a listbox. If I select one of these results I want to receive the range, where the original data is located i.e. Sheets(2).Range("A31")

I already tried to read the range through including the search result in a scripting.dictionary which is based not on my own code.
It exits with error 1004 on line `Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2, Range("A"& lngRow))`

```
Dim Dic As Object
Dim MyRng As Range, Dn As Range, Rng As Range
Dim lngRow As Long

lngRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2", Range("A" & lngRow))
Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
For Each Dn In Rng
    If Not Dn.Value = "" Then
        Set Dic(Dn.Value) = Dn
    End If
Next


  With ListBox1
   Set MyRng = Dic(.Value)
    MsgBox MyRng.Address
End With
```

First, I try only to identify the range of the datasource and display it in a MsgBox.

Later on, I want to add a textbox. A value which is entered there, should be written into a cell, after hitting a button.

Example: I enter the value "5" and click on the button. Now the code should recognize, that my selected listbox item can be found in `Sheet(2).Range("A31")`. My chosen value "5" now should be written into the next free cell of that certain row i.e. `Sheet(2).Range("A31")`

For now, I am stuck to identify the datasource range. The rest can be figured out by me :-)

Thank you in advance for your ideas and help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your desired output?  You have both the found and print range to be `Sheets(2).range("a31")`

Comment: How are you determining what goes into the listbox?  are you initializing the userform and setting the `listbox.list = array_`?  you can simply refer to the `array_(i).address`, where i is the point in the array.

Comment: Your syntax for: `Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2, Range("A"& lngRow))` should be `Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A" & lngRow)`

Comment: Dear Cyril

I search through the list with by using a textbox and the "chanve()" event. The results are stored in an array. 

Your 3. answer helped and it works now. My message box appears and shows the range of the search result. 
`Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A" & lngRow) 

You are my hero!

Thank you all for the provided ideas. Good guys! :-) I am going on with my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting comment as Answer since it appeared to answer the original issue:

Your syntax for:

```
Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2, Range("A"& lngRow))
```

should be

```
Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A" & lngRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always add another column to Listbox, which can be hidden for user

`Me.Listbox.AddItem
Me.Listbox.List(i, 0) = 5
Me.Listbox.List(I, 1) = Range("A31").Address(False, False)`

Now you can read it from Listbox

EDIT:

I have optimized your code and works just fine

```
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim my_sheet As Worksheet
Dim MyRng As Range, Dn As Range, Rng As Range

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
Set my_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set Rng = my_sheet.Range(my_sheet.Cells(1, 1), my_sheet.Cells(my_sheet.Range("a65000").End(xlUp).Row, 1))

For Each Dn In Rng

    dict.Add Trim(Dn.Value), Rng.Address(False, False)

Next

Me.ListBox1.AddItem "0"

With Me.ListBox1

    Set MyRng = my_sheet.Range(dict(.List(0)))

End With

Debug.Print MyRng.Address(False, False)
```

Comment: This helps if I know before, that my ListboxItem is based on Range("A31"). But I do not know in advance. In Sheet(2) there is a very big list. 

Maybe I should try an inversed search ---> search the selected listbox item based on the text of column 1? 

Sorry, but I am really stuck on it for several days and my head is just smoking over this issues.

Comment: Are you able to share the example(file)? I would like to have a closer look. I think there might be very easy solution, but without Userform and Sheet data source I can only guessing

Comment: Cyril could manage to help me. Unfortunately, I cannot mark the question as answered as it was through a comment. I made a mistake by 'Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2, Range("A"& lngRow))' 

It should simply be 'Set Rng = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A" & lngRow)'

Thank you nevertheless for your help and idea! :-)

Comment: You can also take a look at my EDIT if you think that's better :) Glad you found solution ;)